# Why I am getting `this.props.data is undefined` error?

Tags: json, reactjs, entity-framework, webpack, asp.net-core-mvc

I was egzecuting tutorial:
[CLICK](https://reactjs.net/getting-started/tutorial.html)

And I am getting error: `this.props.data is undefined`.

I was implementing the tutorial in my test application, where I was testing also various React tools, so I have not copy-pasted it in 100%. I am using ASP.NET Core MVC and React, own architecture (for test application) and I did not installed all npm's from the tutorial. But I belive, that it is syntax or architecture problem. I am guessing, that calling server's data is corrupted somehow in `app.js` or `CommentBox.js`.

Error from console:

```
TypeError: this.props.data is undefined[Więcej informacji] bundle.js line 541 > eval:45:17
The above error occurred in the <CommentList> component:
    in CommentList (created by CommentBox)
    in div (created by CommentBox)
    in CommentBox (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
react-dom.development.js:14226
[Przełącz szczegóły wiadomości] TypeError: this.props.data is undefined[Więcej informacji]
```

Main `app.js` file that returns to `index.js`:

```
(...)
return (
                <div className="App">
                    <div className="App-header">
                        Welcome to React!
                        <AddProject addProject={this.handleAddProject.bind(this)}/>
                        <Projects onDelete={this.handleDeleteProject.bind(this)} projects={this.state.projects} />
                        <CommentBox url="/comments" pollInterval={2000}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
    (...)
```

In my `component` folder all parent and children files:

`CommentBox.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import uuid from 'uuid';
import CommentList from '../components/CommentList';
import CommentForm from '../components/CommentForm';

class CommentBox extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { data: this.props.initialData };
    }
    loadCommentsFromServer() {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('get', this.props.url, true);
        xhr.onload = () => {
            const data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            this.setState({ data: data });
        };
        xhr.send();
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadCommentsFromServer();
        window.setInterval(() => this.loadCommentsFromServer(), this.props.pollInterval);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="commentBox">
                <h1>Comments</h1>
                <CommentList data={this.state.data} />
                <CommentForm/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default CommentBox;
```

`CommentList.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import uuid from 'uuid';
import Comment from '../components/Comment';

class CommentList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function (comment) {
            return (
                <Comment name={comment.name} key={comment.productID}>
                </Comment>
            );
        });
        return (
            <div className="commentList">
                {commentNodes}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default CommentList;
```

`Comment.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import uuid from 'uuid';

class Comment extends React.Component {
    rawMarkup() {
        const md = new (global.Remarkable || window.Remarkable)();
        const rawMarkup = md.render(this.props.children.toString());
        return { __html: rawMarkup };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="comment">
                <h2 className="commentName">
                    {this.props.name}
                </h2>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default Comment;
```

Comment: You are not passing an `initialData` prop to `CommentBox`, so the `data` given to `CommentList` will be `undefined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, *way* too much code. Try to be as concise as possible.

Your issue is that `this.state.data` in `CommentBox` is `undefined` / `null` initially. Make sure that you're passing the `initialData` prop into `CommentBox` or handling the `null` case in `CommentList`

```
var commentNodes = (this.props.data || []).map(function (comment) {
  return (
    <Comment name={comment.name} key={comment.productID}>
    </Comment>
  );
});
```

Comment: Really liked that approach: `(this.props.data || []).map` One more thing to note!